# Kullback Leibler (KL) Divergence (In the Context of `t-SNE`)

Tags: probability, machine-learning, information-theory

KL Divergence (T-Sne)
I have $$ C = \sum_{i} KL(P_i ||Q_i) = \sum_{i} \sum_{j} \mathbf{p}_{(j|i )} \log \frac{\mathbf{p}_{(j|i)}} {\mathbf{q}_{(j|i)}}$$

This is your basic KL divergence.$P_i$ represents the conditional probability distribution over all given data-points given $x_i$ , and $Q_i$ represents the conditional probability distribution over all map points given $y_i$. I understand that this is asymmetric.

I am not able to understand this line "In particular, there is a large cost for using far map points to represent data-points that are close (i.e, using a small qj|i to model a large pj|i)." can anybody help in understanding this statement. Here is the link to full [paper](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~rshamir/abdbm/scribe/17/lec05.pdf) pg 2

Comment: At least tell the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at the paper. I think that sentence is helping you read the formula by pointing out that when $p_{j|i} >> q_{i|j}$ the term with   $\log(p/q)$ contributes a lot to the $KL$ metric but the term with $\log(q/p)$ contributes very little. It explains in words what that asymmetry means in this particular application.

Comment: I did understand that part. I think what i really don't understand is this statement  "The small cost comes from wasting some of the probability mass in the relevant Q distributions". The sentence mentions that you are converting probability distribution to another. And in doing so you transferring some mass. I did not understand how to you or why do you  waste some mass.